# Electron start app in windows taskbar overflow corner

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Currently I just don't `show` my `BroswerWindow` and create a `Tray`, but this just puts the tray into the normal taskbar. However, apps like slack seem to place themselves in the taskbar overflow corner. How can I control where in the taskbar the app goes from electron?

Edit: it seems after publishing my app it starts in the overflow section.